# Exported CSV from MySQL doesn't appear in specified directory

Tags: mysql, sql, ssh, export

I'm trying to figure out the syntax to export the results of a MySQL query to the desktop as a CSV file via SSH. Here's what I'm trying:

```
 SELECT * INTO OUTFILE 'C:\Users\Jim Smith\Desktop\zyzyz.csv'
 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
 OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"'  
 LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' 
 from <table> limit 5;
```

The query itself works fine, but the file doesn't appear on the desktop. What should I change to get it to show up?

Comment: avoid space between folder name or in anywhere in path

Comment: How should I rewrite it?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

**LINUS Path**

```
SELECT *
FROM tableName
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/fileName.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

And here is reference link http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/1475/save-mysql-query-results-into-a-text-or-csv-file/

**[EDIT]**

Take a look in Task Manager, if any instance of .csv file exists, then delete then try this

**WINDOWS Path**

```
SELECT * INTO OUTFILE 'd:\backups\php\export\data.csv' 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' 
ESCAPED BY '\' 
LINES TERMINATED BY 'n' 
FROM tableName;
```

Comment: I believe that only works for Linux; I don't have a tmp folder on Windows

Comment: change path according to you, I think that make sense

Comment: I would use 'C:\Users\Jim Smith\Desktop\zyzyz.csv', but you're saying I can't have a space. How should I fix that, while still keeping the same path?

Comment: try to use backslash '/'   instead of fowardslah '\'

Comment: I get this error:

`ERROR 1 (HY000): Can't create/write to file '/Users/Jim Smith/Desktop/zyzyz.csv' (Errcode: 2 - No such file or directory)`

Comment: Jim Smith is the name of the user

Comment: I get the same error; I think it's the way I'm writing out the path. Even if I was writing it out correctly, the file I created manually wouldn't be overwritten due to the nature of the export.

Comment: and also try creating file in any other path first, so we can sure that query is working, only path will only the issue.  use any c drive path    say C:\datafiles\file.csv

Comment: I've tried creating the file in other paths (using the syntax in the original question), but the file hasn't shown up there.

Comment: How do I check if any instance of .csv file exists?

Comment: may be something like iexplore.exe in taskmanager Processes, then End Process